# Creating non-smoothed / Stepped DEM from contours (ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, dem, contour

I am attempting to create an artificial DEM that is stepped / not smoothed (imagine the profile below). I have created contours for levels A & B

[image]

Topo to Raster produces a smoothed profile (see below), even with discrete_error_factor set to <0.1

[image]

I've had some success with r.surf.contours in QGIS - however I am trying to recreate the workflow in ESRI products

[image]

Comment: What does your qgis success look like, we have nothing to compare it with?

Comment: Did you try to add more contour

Comment: Have you looked at the slice tool? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/slice.htm It seems that your solution might depend on the specifics, like how big you want your "steps" to be.

Comment: Does the final DEM need to be a raster.  What about making a TIN from your lines?

Comment: @Hornbydd QGIS came out pretty much like the paint sketch - I have added an image above

Comment: @J.R  That could be a workaround - I will try and add more contours

Comment: @GBG Yes unfortunately needs to be a raster, as the next step is comparing the theoretical DEM with actual LiDAR derived DTM

Comment: Please decide whether it’s the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of the ArcGIS Desktop product that you wish to ask about in this particular question. I suggest getting an answer for the former is more likely.